# Linux Forking and adding linux system calls

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This is a very generic question to which i tried googling a lot before posting this question here.

I am starting to learn to forking linux kernel. For this i am following the book
"Professional linux architecture". However this book is a little too advance for me and i am having a hard time grasping concept. 
Could anyone kindly suggest me some resource / books ?

Comment: Do you know well enough [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ? Did you look inside http://kernelnewbies.org/ ?

Comment: Actually, i have been working as a c, c++ programmer for about 5 years now. My work also included embedded system programming and working on data structure and algorithms.  I saw the link, it's about advanced linux programming. Should  go through the beginners guide or is it possible to dive into the advanced version?

Comment: Good start might be "Linux Kernel Development Robert Love".